# How do I use jQuery to make my images zoom in even if they are different sizes?

Tags: jquery, image, hover, zooming

I have relatively simple question. The code below allows me to zoom in on an image at 20% and sliding text comes up when I hover over it. What I would like to do is extend the code so I can access other classes so I can make other photos have the same effect. All my photos are different sizes so it's not as simple as just adding the same class to each image.

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
    //move the image in pixel
     var move = -15;
    //zoom percentage, 1.2 =120%
      var zoom = 1.2;

    //On mouse over those thumbnail
    $('.zitem').hover(function() {

    //Set the width and height according to the zoom percentage
    width = $('.zitem').width() * zoom;
    height = $('.zitem').height() * zoom;

    //Move and zoom the image
    $(this).find('img').stop(false,true).animate({'width':width, 'height':height, 'top':move, 'left':move}, {duration:200});

    //Display the caption
    $(this).find('div.caption').stop(false,true).fadeIn(200);
      },
  function() {
    //Reset the image
    $(this).find('img').stop(false,true).animate({'width':$('.zitem').width(), 'height':$('.zitem').height(), 'top':'0', 'left':'0'}, {duration:100});  

    //Hide the caption
    $(this).find('div.caption').stop(false,true).fadeOut(200);
      });
      });
</script>
```

Comment: I suggest you read through http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring. It will teach you how to create 12 additional instances.

Comment: Thanks I'll check it out tomorrow. I should probably go to bed now.